# Using additional WHERE in SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT events.*, leagues.lname as leagueName,leagues.aliasname as AliasName, t1.tname as team1_name, t2.tname as team2_name 
FROM events 
INNER JOIN leagues ON events.leagueid = leagues.id 
INNER JOIN teams AS t1 ON events.teamhid = t1.teamid 
INNER JOIN teams AS t2 ON events.teamaid = t2.teamid 
WHERE sdate='1352835000' ";
```

It gives TABLE with *COLUMNS*:

```
id sdate ... leagueName AliasName team1_name team2_name
```

How could I add additional conditions:

```
WHERE AliasName LIKE 'word' AND (team1_name LIKE 'word2' OR  team2_name LIKE 'word3')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't use `ALIAS` of column on (*which is in-line with*) `where` clause, so in your case you need to use the `tableName.columnName` (*aside from wrapping it in a subquery*)

```
WHERE leagues.aliasname LIKE 'word' AND 
     (t1.tname LIKE 'word2' OR  t2.tname LIKE 'word3')
```

the reason why you can't use is because the order of execution of the query is as follows

- FROM clause            (*you can set TABLE alias here*)
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause    (*COLUMN alias here*)
- ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      events.*, 
      leagues.lname as leagueName,
      leagues.aliasname as AliasName, 
      t1.tname as team1_name, 
      t2.tname as team2_name 
    FROM events 
    INNER JOIN leagues ON events.leagueid = leagues.id 
    INNER JOIN teams AS t1 ON events.teamhid = t1.teamid 
    INNER JOIN teams AS t2 ON events.teamaid = t2.teamid 
    WHERE sdate = '1352835000'
)  t
WHERE AliasName LIKE 'word'
  AND (team1_name LIKE 'word2' OR  team2_name LIKE 'word3')
```